# How does Xamarin implement an iOS <TableSection> and how can I find out the exact size of the header and color?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I would like to implement a `<TableView>` using a `<StackLayout>`.  Is there a place that I can go to find the dimensions and size of the `<TableView>` elements. Also is the code that Xamarin uses to render this open source and where can I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole Xamarin.Forms code is open-source and on GitHub: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms

The specific part you are looking for, rendering a `TableView` happens here for [Android](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/TableViewRenderer.cs). I think on iOS it is part of the `ListViewRenderer`, which can be found [here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Renderers/ListViewRenderer.cs).